# Recognizing Series Expansions within a Matrix

Tags: matrices

Suppose I have the following matrix (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUwrCxqOQVU):

$$
Q = \begin{bmatrix}
-q_{11} & q_{12} & q_{13} & q_{14} \\
q_{21} & -q_{22} & q_{23} & q_{24} \\
q_{31} & q_{32} & -q_{33} & q_{34} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
= \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
-q_{11} & q_{12} & q_{13} & q_{14} \\
q_{21} & -q_{22} & q_{23} & q_{24} \\
q_{31} & q_{32} & -q_{33} & q_{34} \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]$$

$$q_{ii} = -\sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{m} q_{ij}$$

Based on this matrix, I define:

$$T = \begin{bmatrix}
-q_{11} & q_{12} & q_{13} \\
q_{21} & -q_{22} & q_{23} \\
q_{31} & q_{32} & -q_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$r = -T \cdot \mathbf{1} = \begin{bmatrix}
q_{14} \\
q_{24} \\
q_{34} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

**Can someone show me how I can manipulate/combine the above terms to get:**

$$ \pi_(t) = \pi_0 e^{Qt} = 
\pi_0 \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(Tt)^k}{k!} & \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{T^{(k-1)} (t^k) r}{k!} \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I know that I have to use the following series expansion identities, but I am not exactly sure how to do this:

$\exp(Qt) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(Qt)^n}{n!} =  I + Qt + \frac{1}{2!} Q^2t^2 + \frac{1}{3!} Q^3t^3 + \ldots$

$$e^{Tt} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(Tt)^k}{k!}$$